# Check if src exists on the page

Tags: jquery, find, attr

I have a script that generates img tags, and i want to make sure the same img isn't being made twice. This is the script i tried to create:

```
var included = 0;
var src = "";

jQuery.fn.checkCard = function() {
    if ($("#L_S_Inner").find($('img').attr(src))){
        included = 0;
    } else {
        included = 1;
    }
}
```

However it doesn't work. Not sure what i'm doing wrong here...

It's framed this way so that i can just check the variable 'included' in my img creation script.

*EDIT*

Added the img creation script:

```
$('#Results a').live('dblclick', function() {
    src = $(this).attr('href');
    getC = $(this).attr('class');
    checkCard();

    if (!(checkCard)) {
            $(this).parent().append($('<img />', {'src': src, 'class': 'DCT ' + getC + ''}));
    }
});
```

Comment: Is that the whole function? From what I see src is set to an empty string and never changed. If that is the case then your if statement will never match any of the images on your page because they would all have (presumably) a src attribute.

Comment: Would you be able to post your image-generating script as well? Also, as written, your question seems to be answered by @sosborn's comment (and +1 to that comment!).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Several problems here. First off, despite your explanation, I don't see the need for the global variable. It's ugly and dangerous practice - it should be the return value of the function, unless you have damned good reasons not to do it that way.

Second, the as @sosborn says, the function does not have an input parameter - the `src` is either another global (that you haven't shown), or the code just can't work.

Next, inside `find` there should be a selector, not a jQuery object, and inside `attr` there should be an attribute name (thus, a string `"src"`), not a value (presumably `src` contains something like `http://...`).

Also, why make it into a jQuery plugin?

Literal solution of the problem, I'd do this way:

```
var checkCard = function(src) {
    return !!($('#L_S_Inner img[src="' + src + '"]').length);
}
```

A better yet solution is to remember what images you create by tracking them manually - much faster.

```
var included = [];
// ...
// when you make an image
included[src] = true;
// ...
// when you want to know if it is there
if (included.hasOwnProperty(src)) // ...
```

**UPDATE**: With the creation code posted, let me rewrite the second solution:

```
var included = [];
$('#Results a').live('dblclick', function() {
    var src = $(this).attr('href');
    var getC = $(this).attr('class');

    if (!included.hasOwnProperty(src)) {
        $(this).parent().append($('<img />', {'src': src, 'class': 'DCT ' + getC + ''}));
        included[src] = true;
    }
});
```

By the way, notice the `var`s I added to your inner variables. Declare your variables, it's good for health.

Comment: Hey, what does return !!( do?

Comment: @tfbox: Turns stuff into boolean - truey things into `true`, falsy things into `false`. Specifically, in this case, `.length` is an integer - thus, anything `1` or above to `true`, and `0` to `false`.

Comment: @Amadan - Added the creation script. Sorry about that, i should have done that initially.

Comment: @Amadan - how weird, i couldn't get this to work yesterday, but i just tried it again, and it worked! Thanks for all your help!